# USD - Close Event of a Hosted Control

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, unified-service-desk

I have created a Hosted Control with following configuration:

**Unified Service Desk Component Type: CCA Hosted Application**

**Hosted Application: Hosted Control**

I want to perform some action on the closure of this hosted control inside Unified service Desk but I am unable to find any Close event for this type of configuration.

Is it possible for me to create my own custom close event?

I am using USD 4.1 and CRM 8.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new event record. Some of these pre-defined events (such as Close) are not created by default.

Create a new event, name it `Closing` and populate the Hosted Application field to the Hosted Control you want it to fire on. Make sure you add it to the Configuration record you are using as well before you try it!